# TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I've tried to use fetch to call from backend using react, without libs (such as Axios). So I created this function:

```
export function api(url, method, body, isHeaderContentType,isRequestHeaderAuthentication,header, succesHandler, errorHandler) {
const prefix = 'link';
console.log("url:",prefix+url);
const contentType = isHeaderContentType ? {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
} : {};
const auth = isRequestHeaderAuthentication
    ? {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${AuthUtils.getTokenUser}`,
    }
    : {};
fetch(prefix + url, {
    method,
    headers: {
        ...contentType,
        ...auth,
        ...header,

    },
    protocol:'http:',
    body,
})
    .then(response => {
        response.json().then(json => {
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log("method", json);
                if (succesHandler) {
                    succesHandler(json)
                }
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(json)
            }
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("error",`${url}  ${err}`);
        if (errorHandler) {
            errorHandler(err);
        }
    })
```

}
and call it like this

```
api(
            `link`,
            "GET",
            null,
            true,
            true,
            null,
            response => {
                this.setState({profile:response.data})
            },
            err => {
                console.log('error', err);
            }
        );
```

i call my api() inside this function:

```
getProfileUser = () =>{
    if (!isUserAuthenticated()){
        history.push('/signin')
    }else {
        api(
            `link`,
            "GET",
            null,
            true,
            true,
            null,
            response => {
                this.setState({profile:response.data})
            },
            err => {
                console.log('error', err);
            }
        );
    }
};
```

this is my full component:

```
export default class Profile extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        profile:[]
    }

}
getProfileUser = () =>{
    if (!isUserAuthenticated()){
        someCode
    }else {
        api(
            `link`,
            "GET",
            null,
            true,
            true,
            null,
            response => {
                this.setState({profile:response.data})
            },
            err => {
                console.log('error', err);
            }
        );
    }
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.getProfileUser();
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            hello 
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

but when i tried to run it, i got an error like this

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid value

Is there anyone who knows what's wrong with my code? The function works when I use the "POST" method, but it doesn't work when I use "GET" method

Comment: When are you calling `api()`? Are you calling it within a component life cycle method? If so, which one?

Comment: @Stretch0 yes i tried to call it on componentwillmount

Comment: Does it work if you try calling it in `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: @Stretch0 no,i still got the same error

Comment: Can we see your code for your component where you are calling `api()`?

Comment: this is a weird problem, but can you try adding this? const fetch = window.fetch.bind(window);

Comment: @Stretch0 i've edit my question and show where i call the api()

Comment: @RaihanParlaungan that doesn't really show me much. Was hoping to see the whole component so I could try replicate the issue. I would also recommend what Sujit suggested `const fetch = window.fetch.bind(window)`

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier i've try but it doesn't work

Comment: @Stretch0 i've edit my quetion again and show the entire component

Comment: do you run this in a browser? why w in window is uppercase?

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating your example due to unknown variables but as you can see here https://codesandbox.io/s/w6515zk3zk fetch is working by calling `window.fetch`. Are you able to replicate what I have done or are you able to do get your code running in the react sandbox env?

Comment: I found the error, it only shows whenever I use the Authorization header.

Comment: it's solved i tried to add some cors lib on my django backend

Comment: I know this is an older post, but maybe this can help the next person who encounters this. I was trying to grab a bearer token from firefox using the web tools. What firefox was doing was putting a '...' in the middle of the token and shortening it. Very hard to see. I had to switch the output to raw and copy it from there. What did hint me into looking was another comment here mentioned to look for invalid characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

**Double-check the value in your Authorization header for invalid characters:**

This also happened to me when I tried to add an `Authorization` header to my fetch calls, due to an invalid character in the **`Authorization`** **`key`**.

In my case it was caused by a newline (`\n`) character in the header string, i.e. `Bearer:\nsomelong-token`. Changing the new line to a space solved the problem.

Note, that most special characters are typically not valid for authorization tokens.

Comment: Happened to me as I had an other character (the one you cannot see easily). Good hint.

Comment: I use encodeURI for all headers in client and decodeURI in node. Solves the prob.

Comment: I got this issue because I copied the Authorization header from Firefox Developer Tools without checking "raw" so the value was shortened with "..." in the middle.

Answer (score 23):

For me, i had an invalid character in a **key** of the header object. I accidentally included the ":" and this throws the error described. Really difficult to visually see in the chrome console. Hope it helps someone.

```
{ 'Authorization:':'Bearer etc...' }
```

Comment: This was very hard to find.  Thanks for sharing, it's not obvious when this occurs!

Comment: @tresf Knowing the suffering this inflicted on me - I'm very happy I could relieve someone else of it!

Comment: Thanks, I had the same error. Would've never found in in my js without this.

Answer (score 8):

I had this when passing a string with a newline character into the header object for example:

```
const myString = 'this is a string \nand this is a new line';
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    'subscriptionId': myString
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. When there are unallowed characters in any of the parameters, one may run into such problems. Make sure you use trim() for your strings before passing them as arguments to any function. Most especially with REST services

Answer (score 5):

Hey I was facing the same issue while I was trying to load data using the fetch method in react.

```js
const response = await fetch('/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query
  })
});
```

I had an extra space in the Content-Type that was causing the error so please look for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, but working with Angular 7, I was using a Interceptor service like this:

```
// headerservice.ts
public intercept() {
    const token = Cookies.get('token');
    this.Language = Cookies.get('language');
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders(
      {
        Authorization: 'JWT ' + token,
        'Accept-Language': this.Language
      }
    );
    return this.headers;
  }

  //other file 
   this.headers = this.headersService.intercept();
```

But it doesn´t work on the other file where i am doing the fetch, so i remove the service and put the headers directly inside the function and it works! 
like this:

```
const token = Cookies.get('token');
const language = Cookies.get('language');
const headers = { 
 Authorization: 'JWT ' + token,
'Accept-Language': language
}
const fetchParams = { method: 'GET',
           headers: (headers) };
fetch(url, fetchParams)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the error occurred because I included a "body" on a GET request when calling fetch(). Excluding the body for GET requests solved the problem (e.g., if you're writing a generic function or framework that handles different HTTP request types). Here's a simple code excerpt to illustrate the solution (obviously this code would need expansion in the real world, but it makes the point):

```js
// Earlier code that specifies the HTTP method
let method = 'GET';

// Create fetch() init object
let fetchInit = {};
if (method !== 'GET') {
  fetchInit.body = yourRequestBody;
}

// Start network request
fetch(url, fetchInit).then...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me as well, however with different circumstances. I would like to share it in case someone else has this issue.

So I got the error "**TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid value**" when I tried to upload a file with HTTP POST without using FormData. To solve the issue I used FormData object and appended properties and file itself:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', fileName);
formData.append('data', file);
```

then I used fetch to send the file with POST method. Here is pseudo code:

```
const options = {method: 'POST', formData};
fetch('http://www.someURL.com/upload', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

i've solve this problem with adding my frontend url to whitelist cors of my backend code

Answer (score 0):

In my case it occurred because I wrote "Content Type" instead of "Content-Type"

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I stringified my headers like this:

```
fetch(http://example.com,
{
    credentials: "include",
    headers: JSON.stringify({
        foo: localStorage.getItem("foo"),
    }),
})
```

I fixed it by removing the JSON.stringify:

```
fetch(http://example.com,
{
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
        foo: localStorage.getItem("foo"),
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue-
"Undocumented
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Value is not a valid ByteString."

while testing with Swagger. It got resolved after I checked my token that has ... in between. Please be sure to copy token from Web browser they tend to put elipsis(...) if string is long.

Comment: Another reason could be your are not copying entire token.. check token value thoroughly to identify cause.. Generally in chrome browser token shown under SSOToken{ tkn is short one and below after sub tkn is correct

Answer (score -2):

For me the solution was to not send body on GET method.

```js
async request(url, method, data) {
    const options = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        method: method,
        credentials: "include"
    };

    if (['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'].includes(method)) {
        options.body = JSON.stringify(data);
    }

    return await fetch(url, options);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code sample you used for future reference by others?