# Reactjs - TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from ***.**.*.***:2000

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

This is my reactjs code and I am having problem with fetch. I have created own api using nodejs and trying to retrieve some demo json using get method. I am using same local IP for both reactjs and nodejs, yes i am using different port.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(' ***.**.*.***:2000', {
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });console.log(error)
                }
            )
    }
    render() {
            return (
                <ul>fdg
{/*                    {this.state.items.map(item => (
                        <li key={item.id}>
                            {item.name}
                        </li>
                    ))}*/}
                </ul>
            );

    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Error is shown after fetch is failed

```
  TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL
 from  ***.**.*.***:2000
         at App.componentDidMount (index.js:15)
         at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:14361)
         at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:15462)
         at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
         at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
         at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
         at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:15603)
         at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:16618)
         at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:16563)
         at performWork (react-dom.development.js:16482)
         at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:16454)
         at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:16354)
         at scheduleWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:16218)
         at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:16785)
         at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:16812)
         at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:16839)
         at ReactRoot../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render
 (react-dom.development.js:17122)
         at react-dom.development.js:17262
         at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:16679)
         at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:17258)
         at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:17317)
         at Object../src/index.js (index.js:48)
         at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap d08df1f09c74587853fb:678)
         at fn (bootstrap d08df1f09c74587853fb:88)
         at Object.0 (index.js:49)
         at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap d08df1f09c74587853fb:678)
         at ./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports (bootstrap d08df1f09c74587853fb:724)
         at bootstrap d08df1f09c74587853fb:724
```

Comment: Similar issue was mentioned here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50161808/4510870

Comment: @NirajPaudel No its not similar error. that is invalid value and this is failed to parse url.

Comment: @ShivendraGupta what is second argument

Comment: It looks like you have obfuscated the URL that the error message says is the problem. We can't tell what the problem is without seeing code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone still has the error.
this is my code

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000:graphql',
});
```

I got the url wrong. Should be like this

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
});
```

and if the error in the console is like this:

> Failed to load http://...:2000/: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://...:2000' is
> therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs,
> set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS
> disabled.

Means you have to add cors in your root js

```
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// allow cors origin requests

app.use(cors());
```

Hope I helped. By the way this happened to me so maybe I thought I could help others who has this error. Take Care and Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Here is is some update that i made to code. First i made mistake is i didnt add http:// to my IP address during sending request. After doing that i got another error

> Failed to load http://***.***.*.*:2000/: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://*.*.*.*:2000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Which means i am forgetting to add cors, Information about How to install and use cors inside your express node, can get from this link https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-react-express/

Accepted answer is the example of node express code.