# Adding headers to graphql client causes Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window' error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

This code causes the error and if I remove the headers it does not .I followed the instructions here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication. Here are my cors setting for my backed

```html
  //Cors setting on the backend
origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
```

```js
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL,
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: tokenVar ? `Bearer ${tokenVar}` : '',
    },
  };
});

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  //@ts-ignore
  uri: authLink.concat(link),
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          token: {
            read() {
              return tokenVar();
            },
          },
          userData: {
            read() {
              return userDataVar();
            },
          },
        }
```

Comment: Could you please add some details of the error from stack trace.

Comment: Looks like this is caused from invalid character in the `header`. Please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109878/typeerror-failed-to-execute-fetch-on-window-invalid-value